# How can I set the checked property using vuelidate from an array of options?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I have an array of activities that looks like this:

```
[
    {id: 'd0a503f0-be2b-453c-8f6e-d5a734bbba33, name: 'Baseball'}
    {id: 'd0a503f0..., name: 'Soccer'}
    ...

]
```

I am looping through each activity to render a list of checkbox options like this:

```
<div v-for="activity in activities" :key="activity.id">
    <input :id="`activity-${activity.id}`" 
        v-model="$v.resource.activities.$model" name="activities" :value="activity.id" />
    <label>{{ activity.name }}</label>
</div>
```

So far, things work great. The checkbox group renders with the correct value(s). I am able to check the ones I want and when I save my form, I am saving an array of activity id's.

When I edit the resource, the checkboxes are not being pre-populated (checked). I am struggling to understand how to loop through each of the array elements in [vuelidate's](https://vuelidate.js.org/) `$v.`model.

Let's say I have 4 activities total. Here is what the `$v.resource.activities` attribute looks like in my devtools toolbar (2 activities have been previously selected):

```
$v:Object
   resource
     activities:Object
     $anyDirty:false
     $anyError:false
     $dirty:false
     $error:false
     $invalid:false
     $model:Array[2]
       0:Object
         createdAt:"2023-02-04T08:55:27.009Z"
         id:"d0a503f0-be2b-453c-8f6e-d5a734bbba33"
         name:"Baseball"
         updatedAt:"2023-02-05T23:17:00.206Z"
       1:Object
         createdAt:"2023-02-05T23:19:49.938Z"
         id:"c251e931-2a8a-468c-aff4-b4250233cfa6"
         name:"Soccer"
         updatedAt:"2023-02-05T23:19:49.938Z"
```

I know I need to keep the initial loop like I have above to generate the list of checkboxes. I am confused as to how to also loop through each of the `$model` attributes to see if the checkbox should be checked or not.

Since the value of the checkboxes are only the id of the activity, I don't think it knows what to do (which is understandable). How can I loop through the list of activities and correctly populate which checkbox has been selected?

Comment: As per looking at your console result, your $model is having an array of selected items, and it's not a linear array, it's an array of objects. Just for my understanding, can you please explain if you are using id as a value in the template then how the result is saved as a whole object?

Comment: And if my assumption is right, if you will use `:value="activity"` then the activity will be auto-selected if it is available in the `$v.resource.activities.$model` array.

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you!!!
I was focused so much on only sending the id to the server, I didn't stop to think that I was actually rendering the entire object as the value.